# GCDAsyncSocket data receiving anomalies

Tags: ios, serial-communication, gcdasyncsocket

I'm writing an iPhone app to communicate with a serial device (through the RN-XV serial to wifi board).
The communication protocol is very basic at the moment: the iPhone sends the char 'D' and the serial device answer with a string of values separated by ';' and terminated by LF (\n).

At the moment I'm simulating the serial device with Arduino with the following code:

```
if(Serial.available()){
    char ch = Serial.read();
    if(ch == 'D') Serial.println("04.06.2013 16:52:29 ;1090 ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;71365 ;--- ;2547 ;2547 ;--- ;1467 ;--- ;--- ;0 ;098 ;- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;");
}
```

The string I'm sending is just an example of what the serial device will send.

On the iPhone side I'm using GCDAsyncSocket with the following code:

In the ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mySocketConnection = [SocketConnection getInstance];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(askForData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void) askForData {
    NSData *requestData = [@"D" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [mySocketConnection.myGCDAsocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
    [mySocketConnection.myGCDAsocket readDataWithTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];               
}
```

In SocketConnection.m:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    NSLog(@"Stringa: %@", myString);

    NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    NSLog(@"count = %d", [myArray count]);
}
```

The problem is that it works at 70%:

- most of the time the data I receive are correct (28 objects in the array)
- sometime I don't receive anything (null)
- sometime together with the correct string I receive some more data that I don't know where they come from

This is an example of the output in the XCode Console window:

2013-06-06 00:05:41.767 wakman[2714:907] Connected to Host: 192.168.1.12 port:2000

2013-06-06 00:05:43.868 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: (null)

2013-06-06 00:05:43.870 wakman[2714:907] count = 0

2013-06-06 00:05:45.886 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: (null)

2013-06-06 00:05:45.888 wakman[2714:907] count = 0

2013-06-06 00:05:47.868 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: 04.06.2013 16:52:29 ;1090 ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;71365 ;--- ;2547 ;2547 ;--- ;1467 ;--- ;--- ;0 ;098 ;- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;

2013-06-06 00:05:47.870 wakman[2714:907] count = 28

2013-06-06 00:05:49.893 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: 04.06.2013 16:52:29 ;1090 ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;71365 ;--- ;2547 ;2547 ;--- ;1467 ;--- ;--- ;0 ;098 ;- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;

;--- ;             ***=> where this data come from ?***

2013-06-06 00:05:49.895 wakman[2714:907] count = 30

2013-06-06 00:05:51.892 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: 04.06.2013 16:52:29 ;1090 ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;71365 ;--- ;2547 ;2547 ;--- ;1467 ;--- ;--- ;0 ;098 ;- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;

--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;71365 ;--- ;2547 ;2547 ;--- ;1467 ;--- ;       ***=> where this data come from ?***

2013-06-06 00:05:51.894 wakman[2714:907] count = 44

2013-06-06 00:05:53.890 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: 04.06.2013 16:52:29 ;1090 ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;71365 ;--- ;2547 ;2547 ;--- ;1467 ;--- ;--- ;0 ;098 ;- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;--- ;

2013-06-06 00:05:53.892 wakman[2714:907] count = 28

2013-06-06 00:05:55.886 wakman[2714:907] Stringa: (null)

2013-06-06 00:05:55.888 wakman[2714:907] count = 0              ***=> no data ?***

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Thanks,
Corrado